# Rails: Can't Get Facebook to Find CSS Background Images with Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have tried searching for this answer 100 different ways, but the only things that pop up are inevitably Koala/oauth/devise queries about getting users' Facebook profile pictures, which is not at all what I want.

When you type a link into a Facebook post, Facebook automatically scans that link for images to use with the post.  However, I'm using CSS background images like this:

```
<div class="frame" style="background-image: url(<%= rails_blob_url(@blog.image) if @blog.image.attached? %>)">
```

Which is making Facebook not see them and automatically add it to the post.

Can any of the Rails experts out there tell me what to add to this code to make the image visible to Facebook's automatic image search bots (or whatever webbernet gremlin does the searching when you make a Facebook post)?

Comment: Use meta-tags and add og:image for the images you want Facebook to see

Comment: @WizKid, that is incredibly helpful.  Using the og property I got it to recognize everything but the image.  I have `<meta property="og:image" content="<%= rails_blob_url(@blog.image) if @blog.image.attached? %>" />` in the header and (if I inspect the page source) the link does take me to the right image on S3.  However, Facebook just renders an empty image when I type in the url...

Comment: @WizKid After some quality time with the Facebook Sharing debugger, I got this to work!  Thank you!  (And if you want to write up an answer I'll happily accept it.)